# How to use Column value as Interval to increase date in Oracle SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, date-arithmetic

I have table named REFERENCE with columns TIME (timestamp), and **ADJUST** that stores **varchar seconds values**: 10, 13, 55, .. etc

I want to use the field ADJUST to increase value of TIME while making sure that ADJUST values are converted to seconds and not minutes or other units, something like:

```
SELECT 
TIME AS START,
TIME + ADJUST AS END
FROM REFERENCE;
```

How to that?
I've tried using interval but it works only with explicit values, example:

```
TIME + INTERVAL '13' SECOND AS END
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `numToDSInterval()`:

```
time + numToDSInterval(adjust, 'second')
```

It might be cleaner to explicitly convert the string to a number:

```
time + numToDSInterval(to_number(adjust), 'second')
```

If `adjust` always belongs to range `00-59`, you can also use `to_dsinterval()`:

```
time + to_dsinterval('0 00:00:' || adjust)
```

Comment: This answer worked! I applied to the second form to my real world query and it worked as expected and I verified that added time is logically correct.

My seconds don't belong to range and can be quantitative of seconds like 300 for example. Thanks for the quick response!.

Answer (score 1):

Seconds should be stored as `number`, why are they `varchar` (or probably `varchar2`)?

Other than that, the trick is to take an interval literal (which indeed requires a hard-coded string) and use arithmetic operations on it.

So, let's say `time` and `adjust` are your columns; `time` is in timestamp data type, and `adjust` is number, measured in seconds. (If it's string, you can convert it to number, explicitly, by wrapping it within `to_number()`; I will leave that out, since `adjust` should really be `number` data type to begin with.)

Then you can do something like this:

```
.....  time + adjust * interval '1' second.
```

Here `adjust` can be 300, as in the example you gave under GMB's answer.

Comment: This is a good trick that I'll remember. The table I'm getting seconds values from is a legacy enterprise table that I should only read data from, and I'm in no position to alter its definition or data. And yes ADJUST type is `varchar2`